# VBA for FORMULA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2007

Currently i am using this below formula which gives desired result

```
=IF(ISBLANK('Y:\Reports\FI Daily Reports\1. CP Type Incorrect\[CP Type Incorrect.xlsx]BM_EU_20140705'!M2), 'Y:\Reports\FI Daily Reports\1. CP Type Incorrect\[CP Type Incorrect.xlsx]BM_EU_20140705'!L2, "")
```

but i have around 25 file from which i am extracting information from above formula in different worksheet and number of rows also varies some have around 1000 some even 30000 and even 50000.

problem is every time i opened this excel worksheet which has formula its take time to open obviously due to formula. is there any alternate solution like vba.

I am looking to make file faster probably i thing VBA is will be best or if any other solution is welcome

Comment: Yes, you can use vba.  But, this site is not about teaching you to use vba, giving you pointers on using vba, nor is it a give me the vba code to do this.  Please take the time to research and try to create your own vba to do what you want.  When you get stuck on a SPECIFIC item, come back and ask a question on how to overcome that specific error/problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

You could try a Power Query that runs on the Worksheet open that gets that information for you. Might be marginally faster

Comment: i ma using excel 2007 - not possible in this version